# Python: Issue with "cftime._cftime.DatetimeNoLeap" in applying np.polyfit to an xarray dataset

Tags: python, typeerror, netcdf, python-xarray, trendline

I'm working with CMIP6 NETCdf temperature data with Xarray in Python. I'm able to plot a timeseries at a given point, but cannot create a trendline using np.polyfit. It returns the error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'cftime._cftime.DatetimeNoLeap' and 'float'.

link to file: https://file.io/bKO0rfAp1z8K

My script follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import xarray as xr

dataset = xr.load_dataset("file.nc")
airTemp = dataset['tas']
nome_temperature = airTemp.sel(lat=64.5006, lon=194.5914, method='nearest')

#plotting the timeseries works
plt.plot(nome_temperature.time, nome_temperature.values)

#error when I try to plot the polyfit tredline
z = np.polyfit(nome_temperature.time, nome_temperature.values, 1)
p = np.poly1d(z)
plt.plot(nome_temperature.time, p(nome_temperature.time))
```

Not really sure if this is an issue with time formatting or if I'm just missing a step in changing the time before using it in a trendline. I have no issues with the time in the regular timeseries plot, so I'm unsure what the issues is with the trendline.

Comment: Basically doing math with datetime and numbers breaks. I’d create a new coordinate with the time values converted to int or float with whatever units you want first and then run polyfit with that coordinate as your x axis instead of time.

Comment: This is a leap year free calendar which can be awkward to deal with. You might want to convert it to Gregorian and then switch to int using “days since x” as suggested above